# ANTLR What is simpliest way to realize python like indent-depending grammar?

Tags: antlr, lexer, indentation

I am trying realize python like indent-depending grammar.

Source example:

```
ABC QWE
  CDE EFG
  EFG CDE
    ABC 
  QWE ZXC
```

As i see, what i need is to realize two tokens INDENT and DEDENT, so i could write something like:

```
grammar mygrammar;
text: (ID | block)+;
block: INDENT (ID|block)+ DEDENT;
INDENT: ????;
DEDENT: ????;
```

Is there any simple way to realize this using ANTLR?

(I'd prefer, if it's possible, to use standard ANTLR lexer.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know what the easiest way to handle it is, but the following is a relatively easy way.  Whenever you match a line break in your lexer, optionally match one or more spaces. If there are spaces after the line break, compare the length of these spaces with the current indent-size. If it's more than the current indent size, emit an `Indent` token, if it's less than the current indent-size, emit a `Dedent` token and if it's the same, don't do anything.

You'll also want to emit a number of `Dedent` tokens at the end of the file to let every `Indent` have a matching `Dedent` token.

For this to work properly, you ***must*** add a leading and trailing line break to your input source file!

## ANTRL3

A quick demo:

```java
grammar PyEsque;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  BLOCK;
}

@lexer::members {

  private int previousIndents = -1;
  private int indentLevel = 0;
  java.util.Queue<Token> tokens = new java.util.LinkedList<Token>();

  @Override
  public void emit(Token t) {
    state.token = t;
    tokens.offer(t);
  }

  @Override
  public Token nextToken() {
    super.nextToken();
    return tokens.isEmpty() ? Token.EOF_TOKEN : tokens.poll();
  }

  private void jump(int ttype) {
    indentLevel += (ttype == Dedent ? -1 : 1);
    emit(new CommonToken(ttype, "level=" + indentLevel));
  }
}

parse
 : block EOF -> block
 ;

block
 : Indent block_atoms Dedent -> ^(BLOCK block_atoms)
 ;

block_atoms
 :  (Id | block)+
 ;

NewLine
 : NL SP?
   {
     int n = $SP.text == null ? 0 : $SP.text.length();
     if(n > previousIndents) {
       jump(Indent);
       previousIndents = n;
     }
     else if(n < previousIndents) {
       jump(Dedent);
       previousIndents = n;
     }
     else if(input.LA(1) == EOF) {
       while(indentLevel > 0) {
         jump(Dedent);
       }
     }
     else {
       skip();
     }
   }
 ;

Id
 : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+
 ;

SpaceChars
 : SP {skip();}
 ;

fragment NL     : '\r'? '\n' | '\r';
fragment SP     : (' ' | '\t')+;
fragment Indent : ;
fragment Dedent : ;
```

You can test the parser with the class:

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PyEsqueLexer lexer = new PyEsqueLexer(new ANTLRFileStream("in.txt"));
    PyEsqueParser parser = new PyEsqueParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)parser.parse().getTree();
    DOTTreeGenerator gen = new DOTTreeGenerator();
    StringTemplate st = gen.toDOT(tree);
    System.out.println(st);
  }
}
```

If you now put the following in a file called `in.txt`:

```
AAA AAAAA
  BBB BB B
  BB BBBBB BB
    CCCCCC C CC
  BB BBBBBB
    C CCC
      DDD DD D
      DDD D DDD
```

*(Note the leading and trailing line breaks!)*

then you'll see output that corresponds to the following AST:

[image]

Note that my demo wouldn't produce enough dedents in succession, like dedenting from `ccc` to `aaa` (2 dedent tokens are needed):

```
aaa
  bbb
    ccc
aaa
```

You would need to adjust the code inside `else if(n < previousIndents) { ... }` to possibly emit more than 1 dedent token based on the difference between `n` and `previousIndents`. Off the top of my head, that could look like this:

```java
 else if(n < previousIndents) {
   // Note: assuming indent-size is 2. Jumping from previousIndents=6 
   // to n=2 will result in emitting 2 `Dedent` tokens
   int numDedents = (previousIndents - n) / 2; 
   while(numDedents-- > 0) {
     jump(Dedent);
   }
   previousIndents = n;
 }
```

## ANTLR4

For ANTLR4, do something like this:

```
grammar Python3;

tokens { INDENT, DEDENT }

@lexer::members {
  // A queue where extra tokens are pushed on (see the NEWLINE lexer rule).
  private java.util.LinkedList<Token> tokens = new java.util.LinkedList<>();
  // The stack that keeps track of the indentation level.
  private java.util.Stack<Integer> indents = new java.util.Stack<>();
  // The amount of opened braces, brackets and parenthesis.
  private int opened = 0;
  // The most recently produced token.
  private Token lastToken = null;
  @Override
  public void emit(Token t) {
    super.setToken(t);
    tokens.offer(t);
  }

  @Override
  public Token nextToken() {
    // Check if the end-of-file is ahead and there are still some DEDENTS expected.
    if (_input.LA(1) == EOF && !this.indents.isEmpty()) {
      // Remove any trailing EOF tokens from our buffer.
      for (int i = tokens.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (tokens.get(i).getType() == EOF) {
          tokens.remove(i);
        }
      }

      // First emit an extra line break that serves as the end of the statement.
      this.emit(commonToken(Python3Parser.NEWLINE, "\n"));

      // Now emit as much DEDENT tokens as needed.
      while (!indents.isEmpty()) {
        this.emit(createDedent());
        indents.pop();
      }

      // Put the EOF back on the token stream.
      this.emit(commonToken(Python3Parser.EOF, "<EOF>"));
    }

    Token next = super.nextToken();

    if (next.getChannel() == Token.DEFAULT_CHANNEL) {
      // Keep track of the last token on the default channel.
      this.lastToken = next;
    }

    return tokens.isEmpty() ? next : tokens.poll();
  }

  private Token createDedent() {
    CommonToken dedent = commonToken(Python3Parser.DEDENT, "");
    dedent.setLine(this.lastToken.getLine());
    return dedent;
  }

  private CommonToken commonToken(int type, String text) {
    int stop = this.getCharIndex() - 1;
    int start = text.isEmpty() ? stop : stop - text.length() + 1;
    return new CommonToken(this._tokenFactorySourcePair, type, DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL, start, stop);
  }

  // Calculates the indentation of the provided spaces, taking the
  // following rules into account:
  //
  // "Tabs are replaced (from left to right) by one to eight spaces
  //  such that the total number of characters up to and including
  //  the replacement is a multiple of eight [...]"
  //
  //  -- https://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation
  static int getIndentationCount(String spaces) {
    int count = 0;
    for (char ch : spaces.toCharArray()) {
      switch (ch) {
        case '\t':
          count += 8 - (count % 8);
          break;
        default:
          // A normal space char.
          count++;
      }
    }

    return count;
  }

  boolean atStartOfInput() {
    return super.getCharPositionInLine() == 0 && super.getLine() == 1;
  }
}

single_input
 : NEWLINE
 | simple_stmt
 | compound_stmt NEWLINE
 ;

// more parser rules

NEWLINE
 : ( {atStartOfInput()}?   SPACES
   | ( '\r'? '\n' | '\r' ) SPACES?
   )
   {
     String newLine = getText().replaceAll("[^\r\n]+", "");
     String spaces = getText().replaceAll("[\r\n]+", "");
     int next = _input.LA(1);
     if (opened > 0 || next == '\r' || next == '\n' || next == '#') {
       // If we're inside a list or on a blank line, ignore all indents, 
       // dedents and line breaks.
       skip();
     }
     else {
       emit(commonToken(NEWLINE, newLine));
       int indent = getIndentationCount(spaces);
       int previous = indents.isEmpty() ? 0 : indents.peek();
       if (indent == previous) {
         // skip indents of the same size as the present indent-size
         skip();
       }
       else if (indent > previous) {
         indents.push(indent);
         emit(commonToken(Python3Parser.INDENT, spaces));
       }
       else {
         // Possibly emit more than 1 DEDENT token.
         while(!indents.isEmpty() && indents.peek() > indent) {
           this.emit(createDedent());
           indents.pop();
         }
       }
     }
   }
 ;

// more lexer rules
```

Taken from: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/python3/Python3.g4

Comment: Hi @Bart Kiers, how can I overcome the leading and trailing linebreaks limitation? I tried to make it emit an Indent token programmatically before the starting the parsing, but no luck.

Comment: @0xZhen, feel free to post a question of your own where you can also post the code you're working on. These comment areas aren't well suited for Q&A's.

Comment: @BartKiers just to confirm, is it possible to run grammars with custom code snippets like this with the ANTLR plugin under IntelliJ? I'm getting weird results from it. However when running standalone it's okay. Sadly, I loose the benchmarking information from the plugin and the nice tree views.

Comment: @Har no, the plugin does not run embedded code.

Answer (score 5):

There is an open-source library [**antlr-denter**](https://github.com/yshavit/antlr-denter) for ANTLR v4 that helps parse indents and dedents for you. Check out its [README](https://github.com/yshavit/antlr-denter/blob/master/README.md) for how to use it.

Since it is a library, rather than code snippets to copy-and-paste into your grammar, its indentation-handling can be updated separately from the rest of your grammar.

Answer (score 5):

There is a relatively simple way to do this ANTLR, which I wrote as an experiment: [DentLexer.g4](https://github.com/wevrem/wry/blob/master/grammars/DentLexer.g4). This solution is different from the others mentioned on this page that were written by Kiers and Shavit. It integrates with the runtime solely via an override of the Lexer's `nextToken()` method. It does its work by examining tokens: (1) a `NEWLINE` token triggers the start of a "keep track of indentation" phase; (2) whitespace and comments, both set to channel `HIDDEN`, are counted and ignored, respectively, during that phase; and, (3) any non-`HIDDEN` token ends the phase. Thus controlling the indentation logic is a simple matter of setting a token's channel.

Both of the solutions mentioned on this page require a `NEWLINE` token to also grab all the subsequent whitespace, but in doing so can't handle multi-line comments interrupting that whitespace. Dent, instead, keeps `NEWLINE` and whitespace tokens separate and can handle multi-line comments.

Your grammar would be set up something like below. Note that the NEWLINE and WS lexer rules have actions that control the `pendingDent` state and keep track of indentation level with the `indentCount` variable.

```
grammar MyGrammar;

tokens { INDENT, DEDENT }

@lexer::members {
    // override of nextToken(), see Dent.g4 grammar on github
    // https://github.com/wevrem/wry/blob/master/grammars/Dent.g4
}

script : ( NEWLINE | statement )* EOF ;

statement
    :   simpleStatement
    |   blockStatements
    ;

simpleStatement : LEGIT+ NEWLINE ;

blockStatements : LEGIT+ NEWLINE INDENT statement+ DEDENT ;

NEWLINE : ( '\r'? '\n' | '\r' ) {
    if (pendingDent) { setChannel(HIDDEN); }
    pendingDent = true;
    indentCount = 0;
    initialIndentToken = null;
} ;

WS : [ \t]+ {
    setChannel(HIDDEN);
    if (pendingDent) { indentCount += getText().length(); }
} ;

BlockComment : '/*' ( BlockComment | . )*? '*/' -> channel(HIDDEN) ;   // allow nesting comments
LineComment : '//' ~[\r\n]* -> channel(HIDDEN) ;

LEGIT : ~[ \t\r\n]+ ~[\r\n]*;   // Replace with your language-specific rules...
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the [Python ANTLR grammar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1200715779785/Python.g)?

**Edit: Added psuedo Python code for creating INDENT/DEDENT tokens**

```
UNKNOWN_TOKEN = 0
INDENT_TOKEN = 1
DEDENT_TOKEN = 2

# filestream has already been processed so that each character is a newline and
# every tab outside of quotations is converted to 8 spaces.
def GetIndentationTokens(filestream):
    # Stores (indentation_token, line, character_index)
    indentation_record = list()
    line = 0
    character_index = 0
    column = 0
    counting_whitespace = true
    indentations = list()
    for c in filestream:
        if IsNewLine(c):
            character_index = 0
            column = 0
            line += 1
            counting_whitespace = true
        elif c != ' ' and counting_whitespace:
            counting_whitespace = false
            if(len(indentations) == 0):
                indentation_record.append((token, line, character_index))
            else:
                while(len(indentations) > 0 and indentations[-1] != column:
                    if(column < indentations[-1]):
                        indentations.pop()
                        indentation_record.append((
                            DEDENT, line, character_index))
                    elif(column > indentations[-1]):
                        indentations.append(column)
                        indentation_record.append((
                            INDENT, line, character_index))

        if not IsNewLine(c):
            column += 1

        character_index += 1
    while(len(indentations) > 0):
        indentations.pop()
        indentation_record.append((DEDENT_TOKEN, line, character_index))
    return indentation_record
```

Comment: Yep. This grammar has no implementation of INDENT and DEDENT rules. It seems that this grammar uses not standard lexer...

Comment: @Astronavigator Well, having looked at [Python's Lexical Analysis approach to indentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation), their INDENT and DEDENT tokens are produced in a separate process (which can be performed prior to passing to ANTLR). When you look at it their way, it's much simpler.

Comment: Thanx for answer, JSPerfUnknown. Well, perfoming INDENT and DEDENT tokens prior to passing to ANTLR is a good point. I'll think about it. For now i'd prefer using only standard lexer, so accept Bart's answer.