# ANTLR return group of lexical rules?

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr, interpreter, rules, antlr3

Can I replace **indent_loop[3]** in following grammar with the the group of 3 **INDENT**? 
Where INDENT is lexical rule for indentation.

I just want to write number of **INDENT** based on the number.

```
match_node
        :   match_node_name (tree_operator) (NEW_LINE (indent_loop[3]) ( moduleCall | literals ))*
            { match_node_list.push($match_node_name.text); }
        |   SINGLE_QUOTE POINTE SINGLE_QUOTE 
        ;


    match_node_name
        :   IDENT_SMALL_LETTERS
        ;

    indent_loop[int scope]
        :   {scope == 3}? INDENT INDENT INDENT  
        |   {scope == 4}? INDENT INDENT INDENT INDENT   
        ;

    INDENT :  '\t';
```

When I did this I was not able to come back to my calling rule and was not able to return this group of indentation? 
Means, ( moduleCall | literals ))* was not called.

Where I am wrong? I am just begining.

Or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using a semantic predicate<sup>1</sup>:

```
grammar T;

parse
 : digit[1] digit[2] digit[3] EOF
 ;

digit[int amount]
 : ({amount > 0}?=> DIGIT {amount--;})*
 ;

DIGIT
 : '0'..'9'
 ;
```

Parsing `"456789"` with a parser generated from the grammar above, would result in the following parse:

[image]

Note that in your case, you're simply matching a tab, not necessarily an indentation (i.e. one or more tabs from the start of a line). If you only want to match indentations from the start of the line, the (IMHO) easiest way would be to handle them in the lexer<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> [What is a 'semantic predicate' in ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056441/what-is-a-semantic-predicate-in-antlr)
<sup>2</sup> [ANTLR What is simpliest way to realize python like indent-depending grammar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642154/antlr-what-is-simpliest-way-to-realize-python-like-indent-depending-grammar)