# ANTLR: Space indentation?

Tags: java, antlr, lexer

I want to create a very simple grammar with space indentation. Each line consists of 1 or more words but indentation like python (4 spaces or a tab is one indent) and there is no close for indentation, for example:

```
if something cool occurs
    do this
else
    otherwise do this
    loop around something
       each time doing this
       and do that
say good byte
```

Rather than read each line, calculate the indentation and build a tree manually is it possible to do all of that in ANTLR grammar? My target language is Java.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642154/antlr-what-is-simpliest-way-to-realize-python-like-indent-depending-grammar

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. All you do is define a rule and let it be skipped.

Here you go:

```
Ignore :  (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r')+ {skip();};
```

Or if you need to recognize \n or \r

```
Ignore :  (' ' | '\t')+ {skip();};
```

Add this to your gramar and all spaces and tabs will be ignored.