# Previous token in Antlr3 Parser

Tags: parsing, token, antlr3

How can I get the previous token in Antlr 3 parser?. Actually i can get it easily by using "input.LT(-1)".But I don't want to use the lookahead.So is there any alternative method to get the previous token in parser?

Comment: What is the reason for avoiding `LT(-1)`? As long as you want the previous token before the one currently matched, this is the standard way and is fully supported by ANTLR. Only case I know of where you cannot use it is if you want to know the previous token before some given arbitrary token (not the one actually matched).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way would be to override `emit(Token t)` and `nextToken()` in your lexer and keep track of the last emitted token. For an example of how this could work, have a look at the `PyEsque` grammar from this Q&A: [ANTLR What is simpliest way to realize python like indent-depending grammar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642154/antlr-what-is-simpliest-way-to-realize-python-like-indent-depending-grammar)

But I would just use `input.LT(-1)`.