# How can I import namespaces (e.g. using System.Linq) in Anltr4 / C#

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

I have created a simple **.g4** (Antlr4) grammar & lexer file.

It generates my lexer/parser code fine. 
But after adding some custom code that require Linq extensions I now need to get the custom statement **"using System.Linq;"** injected at the top of my generated lexer code file.

I am aware that there are some options for injecting code (from the .g4 file), e.g.

```
@lexer::members {
     ... {custom lexer code goes here}
```

Can someone please point me to the correct (.g4) syntax that will render the necessary "using" statements in the rendered lexer/parser.

**UPDATE:**
LexLi made a good point .. why do I need that? I'm supposed to write my code in visitor or listener. **Answer to that:** I am trying to implement INDENT and DEDENT tokens in C# (analogue to the the Java code posted here under "ANTLR4": 
[ANTLR What is simpliest way to realize python like indent-depending grammar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642154/antlr-what-is-simpliest-way-to-realize-python-like-indent-depending-grammar)

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need that? You are supposed to write your code in visitor or listener, and no more "actions" in your grammar file like ANTLR 2 or 3 (though they are still supported).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control what is written to your file in the classic way,

```
@parser::header
{
#pragma warning disable 3001, 3003, 3005, 3009, 1591 
}

@lexer::header
{
#pragma warning disable 3001, 3003, 3005, 3009, 1591 
}

@parser::namespace { Lextm.Namespace }
@lexer::namespace { Lextm.Namespace }

@parser::footer
{
#pragma warning restore 3001, 3003, 3005, 3009, 1591 
}

@lexer::footer
{
#pragma warning restore 3001, 3003, 3005, 3009, 1591 
}
```

So in your case, add the `using` statements to header.